# Using Firebase with Google Nest on Android, authentication error

Tags: android, firebase, nest-api

I am building a nest client. I started from the nestDK provided by Nest. I changed the code to use the "pin" authentication method. I successfully retrieve an "access token" using the nest pin workflow.

I updated the nestDK dependency on firebase to the latest version (available from the firebase website). I noticed that the Firebase.auth method was deprecated so I created my own authentication method. I use:

mFirebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(token, authHandler)

I get the following logs:

[android logcat output (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/3Grthxr8)

And that just goes on and on in a loop. Can someone help me understand what this means and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 2):

I found that I was sitting behind some kind of firewall from my university. I connected my phone to another WiFi router without a firewall and the connection to the nest firebase worked fine.